# Show text on image in PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have generated a PDF using the HTMLWorker of iTextsharp. In PDF I want to show text on image marking specific area. For that, I have used div tag with the position but it not showing text on the image, but if I run the same HTML in the browser then it shows text on an image on specific location.

Below is my code which I used to generate the PDF:

```
StringBuilder sReportHeader = new StringBuilder();

sReportHeader.Append("<table style=\"table-layout:fixed\" width=\"100%\" style=\"font-family:Verdana;font-size:8px;\">" +
                        "<tr>" +
                            "<td align=\"left\">" + @"<img src=\"http://localhost/img/image1.jpg\" width=\"520\"></img></td>" +
                        "</tr>" +
                    "</table>" +
                    "<div id=\"divArea1\" style=\"position:absolute;left:50px;top:250px;font-weight:bold;\">Area1</div>");

MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
Document document = new Document();
var worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
document.Open();
worker.StartDocument();
pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
TwoColumnHeaderFooter twopdf = new TwoColumnHeaderFooter();
pdfWriter.PageEvent = twopdf;
twopdf.OnOpenDocument(pdfWriter, document);
worker.Parse(new StringReader(sReportHeader.ToString()));
worker.EndDocument();
worker.Close();
document.CloseDocument();
document.Close();

byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
workStream.Position = 0;
pdfWriter.Flush();
pdfWriter.Close();

return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");
```

> Is there anything which I missing in my code? Or is there another way
>   to show text on the image using iTextsharp?

```
iTextsharp: Version 5.5.13.0
```

Below is the HTML which work correctly in browser:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed" width="100%" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><img src="http://localhost/TheAutoAuction/img/image1.jpg" width="520"></img></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="divArea1" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:250px;;font-weight:bold;">Area1</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the sample you put in your question an actual copy of the code in your project? Not saying it has anything to do with your issue, but there are quite some double quotes that are not escaped in your `sReportHeader.Append`.

Comment: @AsheraH yes it is same code...By mistake, I have removed that escaped character. Now I have updated it. Thanks

Comment: In that version of iText, why do you use the deprecated `HTMLWorker`? I strongly recommend to use `XMLWorker` instead!

Comment: Actually, PDF generated using an older version in past and now recently I need to add an image with text. So I just upgraded the dll for check whether it displays text on image or not.